# How to solve url issue in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have used welcome file as an `index.html` that contains like

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=pages/login.jsp">
```

then url will be like
localhost:8080/Project_Name/pages/login.jsp

after successful login url will be like
localhost:8080/Project_Name/pages/login.action(Home Page)

localhost:8080/Project_Name/pages/somePage.jsp

Here in the somePage.jsp i have form with an action ="myUrl" which is like below form

```
<s: form action="myUrl">

Name:<s:textfield name="Name" />    
<s:submit  value="Submit"  />

<table>
<thead><tr><th>Name</th></tr> </thead>
<tbody>
<s:iterator value="admintimeTable">
<tr>
<td><s:property value="className" /></td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
</tbody>


</s:form>
```

when i click on submit the name will be saved in database and it will display the names which are saved in database successfully 
Now the url will be like

localhost:8080/Project_Name/pages/myUrl.action

then if i click submit again to save name, the name will successfully saved in database but while returning the response the url changed like this
localhost:8080/Project_Name/myUrl.action so that jsp page under pages folder will not be picked

```
<action name="myUrl" class="com.pradeep.sms.controller.SomeClass">
        <result name="success">somePage.jsp</result>        
        </action>  






Web content
|
|
|
|--------Pages
           |
           |
           |----login.jsp
           |----somePage.jsp
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Don't use jsps directly. Use actions. Action -> jsp.

Comment: @RomanC i was solved the issue using namespace configuration but why the form is not going to reset when i expecting output to the same page

Comment: @Nisarganandu If you have another question you should ask it on another page.

Comment: @RomanC To accept answer i need still some more reputation and every time not possible put new questions please tell me submitting form data. the data will be display that time why form is not going to reset

Answer (score 0):

i have solved the issue by adding namespace in struts xml

```
<action name="myUrl" namespace="/pages" class="com.pradeep.sms.controller.SomeClass">
<result name="success">somePage.jsp</result>        
</action>
```